# Accessing another website Login page by API Documentation using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest

I need to access a website login page with my ejs file login page here is my routes for my login page

```
router.get('/login', (req,res)=> {
    
    res.render('login');

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/index',
    failureRedirect : '/',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password. Try Again!!!'
}));
```

here is my documentation of the other website:

```
URL: https://website/restapi/user/signin
POST Request
Resquest Headers:
content-type: application/json
Request Body:
json format
{"username":"VALUE","password":"VALUE"}
Ex:
{"username":"test","password":"test123"}
Response:
In case of success:
Response status:
200 OK
Response Header:
authorization: Bearer
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmYWRpLmhlbnJpQHBoYXJvcy1zb2x1dGlvbnMuZGUiL
CJleHAiOjE1MjU4ODA0OTN9.wNrvFQSH-L4ibgcEhKd-4WE8H3t2P4vYDK8wcGtLIGcaJr0Z
TZPCCeXePaa4HbGvZ9fsgOWgBLCyRYOVTur27w
** The header "authorization" shall be used as request header with same name in any
rest further request
Response body:
json format
{"user":{"id":3,"username":"test","firstname":"Test","lastname":"User","email
":"test@gmail.com",
```

how can I add post routes using this API documentation include authorization?

Comment: You can use axios or fetch api to that

Comment: thanks for the reply but I need how to use it inside my routes?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @syed Mohib uddin i got the results

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'website/rest/user/signin',
    data,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

})
.then(res => console.log(res.headers.authorization))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```